# Magento 2: Some texts are not translated

Tags: localisation, magento2.2.6, i18n

Magento 2.2.6: Some texts are not translated, like Proceed to checkout, Company, Continue Shopping etc.

I am using below string:-

```
"Proceed to Checkout","ادفع الآن",module,Magento_Checkout
"Proceed to Checkout","ادفع الآن",module,Magento_Customer
"Proceed to Checkout","ادفع الآن",theme,frontend/Magento/blank
"Proceed to Checkout","ادفع الآن",theme,frontend/Magento/luma

"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Backend
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Catalog
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Company
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Company
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Customer
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_GiftRegistry
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Invitation
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_MultipleWishlist
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Paypal
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Reports
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_Sales
"Company","الشركة",module,Magento_User
```

Even Last name translated properly as below:-

```
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Backend
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Catalog
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Company
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Customer
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_GiftRegistry
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Invitation
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_MultipleWishlist
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Paypal
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Reports
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_Sales
"Last Name","اسم العائلة",module,Magento_User
```

Please let me know how to define the string in translate CSV to translate in other locale.

Comment: I ended up translating this things using inline translation. Another hack/option is to add the translation to translation table in your database.

Comment: Thanks but I want text in both language

Answer (score -1):

Create a new module for Language translations. Add your own language translation file inside it. It will extend existing language pack if it already exist.
Create registration.php inside module

```
    <?php


\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'yourcompanyname_LanguagePack',
    __DIR__
);
```

crate module.xml file inside etc folder. LanguagePack/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="yourcompanyname_LanguagePack" setup_version="1.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

Then Createfolder i18n inside your module and place all translations files in this folder. for example for french it will be line fr_FR.csv and add french translation against english text.